# Inheriting Values from output.tf with conditional resources using TF 0.12+

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I have a module for service-accounts in GCP being used to populate kubernetes secrets

Here is my module

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  count        = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  account_id   = var.account_id
  display_name = var.display_name
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "service_account_roles" {
  count  = var.enabled ? length(var.roles) : 0
  role   = "roles/${element(var.roles, count.index)}"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account[0].email}"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "service_account_key" {
  count              = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account[0].name
}
```

'output.tf' contains the following

```
output "private_decoded_key" {
  value = base64decode(
    element(
      concat(
        google_service_account_key.service_account_key.*.private_key,
        [""],
      ),
      0,
    ),
  )
  description = "The base 64 decoded version of the credentials"
}
```

Since there is a conditional that none of these resources are created without the `enabled` flag, I had to handle it in TF 0.11.14 this way, and the tf0.12 autoupgrade tool didnt do much changes here.

How can I simplify this in Terraform 0.12.24, 
I tried modifying the output to simply

```
value = base64decode(google_service_account_key.service_account_key[0].private_key)
```

But the problem there is that if the corresponding kubernetes cluster gets deleted during a deletion, and there are errors midway because terraform, I will not be able to cleanup the terraform state of the rest of the resources using 
`terraform destroy'

Attempts to convert the `count` to `for_each` as shown below gave me the following errors

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  # count        = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  for_each     = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
  account_id   = var.account_id
  display_name = var.display_name
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "service_account_roles" {
  # count  = var.enabled ? length(var.roles) : 0
  for_each = var.enabled ? toset(var.roles) : 0
  # role   = "roles/${element(var.roles, count.index)}"
  role     = "roles/${each.value}" 
  member   = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account[0].email}"
}
```

```
for_each = var.enabled ? toset(var.roles) : 0

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are set of dynamic and number, respectively.
```

What am I doing wrong above ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem completely. But As per my understanding are you talking about the condition in output. If you are then you may use `depends_on` with the output values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the terraform version you mentioned (0.12.24) you should be able to use [`try()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/try.html) in your `outputs.tf`:

```
value = try(base64decode(google_service_account_key.service_account_key[0].private_key), "")
```

This would default to `""` if `google_service_account_key.service_account_key[0].private_key` is not resolvable for any reason; you can also default to `null` of course.

**Edit/Update**: To answer second (edited) part of the question:

To get rid of the error that both sides need to have the same type, you need to use `[]` as an empty set instead of `0` when converting to `for_each`:

```
for_each = var.enabled ? toset(var.roles) : []
```

Please pay attention with existing infrastructure as you need to manipulate the state file when converting from `count` to `for_each` or terraform will try to destroy and create resources.

(I will cover this in more detail in part 3 of a series of stories I am currently working on about how to write terraform modules. You can find [part 1 on medium](https://medium.com/mineiros/the-ultimate-guide-on-how-to-write-terraform-modules-part-1-81f86d31f024?source=friends_link&sk=1dbb61a844b4eafd50937c82cdc37e67) and part 2 will be released next week.)

Comment: Do you know how to solve the count to for_each problem above ?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmedNasir updated the answer explaining how to fix your problem.

Comment: Can for_each also be used for conditional resources ?  for_each = var.enabled ? 1 : 0, gives me an error "The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argumentmust be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type
number."

Comment: @ShoaibAhmedNasir you basically find three types of resources in terraform today (as described in my linked article): single resources, bulk resources with `count`, and bulk resources with `for_each`.. it does not make sense to replace all `count` with `for_each` just for the sake of using `for_each`.. so it makes sense to see how the resource will be extended/used in the future.. for single resources I would keep it with `count` to enable/disable them. if you know this will be used as a bulk resource soon, try to make it a `for_each` unless the keys depend on computed values.